# What is a word for someone who hates or intensely dislikes one person?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone who hates or intensely dislikes one person? Misanthrope (hatred of humankind) is exactly what I'm looking for except it is too broad. This is a word I intend to use humorously, if it helps.

Example sentences:

1. Sarah is a ________ because she doesn't hate anybody but Donald Trump.
2. Ben is a poly-_________ because he hates everyone on his swim team.

Comment: FWIW, I don't know of a single word to fit your sample sentences.  That being said, if you intend to say something that is readily understood by native English speakers, you may consider reworking your sentences or allowing a phrase instead of a single word that may or may not be clearly understood.

Comment: Donald Trump is the "bête noire" of Sarah, but Sarah isn't anything special.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/b%C3%AAte%20noire

Comment: Well, I would have no trouble describing the concept, but I would like to find a word if there is one. I also think there might not be one.

Answer (score 2):

A **hater**:

> a person who greatly dislikes a specified person or thing.
>   - [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=active&q=hater)

Comment: Close, but the "or thing" part makes it too vague. I can be an iPhone hater, beach hater, dubstep hater, etc.

Comment: Pretty urban if you ask me.

Comment: "haters gonna hate".  +1

Comment: A coworker suggested "unihater" or "monohater" to me. :) Not quite, but funny.

Answer (score 0):

`Nemesis` came to my mind but I think the dislike must be mutual to make this a suitable term.

[`Antagonist`](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/antagonist#antagonist__2) was my second thought, however this involves opposing action

> A person who actively opposes or is hostile to someone or something; an adversary:

Comment: Yes, I think the lack of opposing action is almost key to the definition. Misanthrope, at least for me, brings to mind a passive person who has an unpleasant opinion.